# Authenticating a user

Tags: c#, wpf, authentication, passwordbox

I've looked through multiple solutions on here and the internet on how to solve this but I can't seem to get it. I'm just trying to make a simple login for an application I'm developing. Eventually I'll have it connected to an SQL database on a server but forget that right now. Here's the code:

```
<Controls:MetroWindow x:Class="ScotiaPlayTrade.Wpf.Application.LoginWindow"
    xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
    xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
    xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:ScotiaPlayTrade.Wpf.Application"              
    xmlns:Controls="clr-namespace:MahApps.Metro.Controls;assembly=MahApps.Metro"
    xmlns:System="clr-namespace:System;assembly=mscorlib" Title="Authentication"
    Height="400" Width="600" WindowStartupLocation="CenterScreen" TitleForeground="#999988"
    ResizeMode="NoResize" WindowStyle="None" WindowState="Normal" ShowMaxRestoreButton="False">

<Grid>
    <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
          <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto"/>
    </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>

    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto"/>
         <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <!--Username Layout-->
    <TextBlock 
         Margin="10,10,10,10" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="0">
        User Name
    </TextBlock>
    <TextBox 
         Margin="10,10,10,10" 
        x:Name="userName" 
        Grid.Column="5" 
        Grid.Row="0" 
        Text="{x:Static System:Environment.UserName}"
        IsReadOnly="True">
    </TextBox>

    <!--Password Layout-->
    <TextBlock 
         Margin="10,10,10,10" 
        Grid.Column="0" 
        Grid.Row="1">
        Password
    </TextBlock>

    <PasswordBox
        Margin="10,10,10,10" 
        Width="200" 
        x:Name="PasswordBox" 
        ff:PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword="true"  x:PasswordBoxAssistant.BoundPassword="{Binding Path=Password, Mode=TwoWay, UpdateSourceTrigger=PropertyChanged}"
        Grid.Column="1" 
        Grid.Row="1">
    </PasswordBox >

    <!--Buttons Layout-->
    <StackPanel Margin="3,3,3,3" Orientation="Horizontal" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="2">
        <Button 
            Margin="10,10,10,10" 
            Click="Login_Click" 
            IsDefault="True">
            Login
        </Button>
        <Button 
            Margin="10,10,10,10" 
            Click="Exit_Click" 
            IsCancel="True">
            Exit
        </Button>

        <Button 
            Margin="10,10,10,10" 
            Click="AddNewUser_Click" 
            IsCancel="True">
            New User
        </Button>

    </StackPanel>
</Grid>
```

That's my LoginWindow.xaml and here's my cs code for the window.

```
public partial class LoginWindow
{
    public LoginWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }

    //Clicking Login Button
    private void Login_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        //Check that password field is not null
        if (PasswordBox != null)
        {
            //Check that username matches password, if it matches then open main window 

            //Launch the main window after authentication is complete
            MainWindow myMainWindow = new MainWindow();
            myMainWindow.Show();

            //Close the login screen
            Close();
        }
        else
        {
            MessageBox.Show("Password field cannot be empty!");

        }


    }

    //Clicking Exit Button
    private void Exit_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        Close();

    }

    //Clicking Exit Button
    private void AddNewUser_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        MessageBox.Show("Not yet implemented");

    }
}
```

I've tried everything with passwordbox it keeps giving me an error that WPF doesn't support it, things like PasswordBoxAssistant, and Helper. Would appreciate any help. Here are the error messages:
Error   1   PasswordBoxAssistant is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.
Error   5   The property 'PasswordBoxAssistant.BindPassword' does not exist in XML namespace 'http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml'. Line 50 Position 13.

Ok so now I made a class called PasswordValidation and added the PasswordBoxAssistant code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows;
using System.Windows.Controls;
using System.Windows.Data;
using System.Windows.Documents;
using System.Windows.Input;
using System.Windows.Media;
using System.Windows.Media.Imaging;
using System.Windows.Shapes;

namespace ScotiaPlayTrade.Wpf.Application
{
    public static class PasswordBoxAssistant
    {
        public static readonly DependencyProperty BoundPassword =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("BoundPassword", typeof(string),       typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(string.Empty, OnBoundPasswordChanged));

        public static readonly DependencyProperty BindPassword = DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached(
            "BindPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(false, OnBindPasswordChanged));

        private static readonly DependencyProperty UpdatingPassword =
            DependencyProperty.RegisterAttached("UpdatingPassword", typeof(bool), typeof(PasswordBoxAssistant), new PropertyMetadata(false));

        private static void OnBoundPasswordChanged(DependencyObject d, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordBox box = d as PasswordBox;

            // only handle this event when the property is attached to a PasswordBox
            // and when the BindPassword attached property has been set to true
            if (d == null || !GetBindPassword(d))
            {
                return;
            }

            // avoid recursive updating by ignoring the box's changed event
            box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;

            string newPassword = (string)e.NewValue;

            if (!GetUpdatingPassword(box))
            {
                box.Password = newPassword;
            }

            box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
        }

        private static void OnBindPasswordChanged(DependencyObject dp, DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            // when the BindPassword attached property is set on a PasswordBox,
            // start listening to its PasswordChanged event

            PasswordBox box = dp as PasswordBox;

            if (box == null)
            {
                return;
            }

            bool wasBound = (bool)(e.OldValue);
            bool needToBind = (bool)(e.NewValue);

            if (wasBound)
            {
                box.PasswordChanged -= HandlePasswordChanged;
            }

            if (needToBind)
            {
                box.PasswordChanged += HandlePasswordChanged;
            }
        }

        private static void HandlePasswordChanged(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
        {
            PasswordBox box = sender as PasswordBox;

            // set a flag to indicate that we're updating the password
            SetUpdatingPassword(box, true);
            // push the new password into the BoundPassword property
            SetBoundPassword(box, box.Password);
            SetUpdatingPassword(box, false);
        }

        public static void SetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
        {
            dp.SetValue(BindPassword, value);
        }

        public static bool GetBindPassword(DependencyObject dp)
        {
            return (bool)dp.GetValue(BindPassword);
        }

        public static string GetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp)
        {
            return (string)dp.GetValue(BoundPassword);
        }

        public static void SetBoundPassword(DependencyObject dp, string value)
        {
            dp.SetValue(BoundPassword, value);
        }

        private static bool GetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp)
        {
            return (bool)dp.GetValue(UpdatingPassword);
        }

        private static void SetUpdatingPassword(DependencyObject dp, bool value)
        {
            dp.SetValue(UpdatingPassword, value);
        }
    }
```

}

The following are the errors I get:
Error   1   The name "PasswordBoxAssistant" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:ScotiaPlayTrade.Wpf.Application".    50  13
Error   2   PasswordBoxAssistant is not supported in a Windows Presentation Foundation (WPF) project.       50  58
Error   3   The attachable property 'BindPassword' was not found in type 'PasswordBoxAssistant'.        50  13

Comment: Post the full details of the error message you're getting, please.

Comment: @Daniel C I've added the the error messages in the post. I'm trying to follow this [link](http://blog.functionalfun.net/2008/06/wpf-passwordbox-and-data-binding.html)

Comment: In the XAML you posted you seem to have commented out the PasswordBoxAssistant attributes. Are they part of your passwordbox in the actual code you're using? Also have you added the namespace for the PasswordBoxAssistant to your page? Please repost your entire current XAML.

Comment: Yea I uncommented that line and put it under x:Name="PasswordBox" and at the top declared xmlns:ff="clr-namespace:ScotiaPlayTrade.Wpf.Application". Then I realized I didn't add the PasswordBoxAssistant class so I made a class called it PasswordValidation and I added the static class for PasswordBoxAssistant in it. See the code above @Daniel C